# Memory problem? dtostr() and strcat()

Tags: arduino-nano, memory-usage

I've been dealing with this for quite a while now and searching all over for answers.. I'm trying to put together two floats into a char*. Separated by a ",".
This is the code I'm working with.

```cpp
#include <DHT.h>
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define DHT_pin 10
#define DHT_type DHT11

DHT dht(DHT_pin, DHT_type);
RH_ASK rf_driver;

float temp;
float hum;

char ch_temp[6];
char ch_hum[6];
char msg_out[12] = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  dht.begin();
  if (rf_driver.init()) {
    Serial.println("Radio transmitter initiated..");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Radio transmitter failed to initiate..");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
void loop() {
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  hum = dht.readHumidity();

  dtostrf(temp, 5, 2, ch_temp);
  dtostrf(hum, 5, 2, ch_hum);
  strcat(msg_out, ch_temp);
  strcat(msg_out, ",");
  strcat(msg_out, ch_hum);

  Serial.println(msg_out);
  rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg_out, strlen(msg_out));
  rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
  Serial.print("data sent, package size: ");
  Serial.println(strlen(msg_out));
  delay(1000);

}
```

I have tried using different sizes of the char arrays, but it just goes crazy.
This is the console output:

```cpp
Radio transmitter initiated..
22.00,34.00
data sent, package size: 11
⸮⸮Radio transmitter initiated..
22.00,34.00
data sent, package size: 11
```

So on its way through the second loop it fails, restarts and then on its third way through it just gives up... What am I doing wrong? :( Really sad over this.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the RF and sensor code, the sketch seems to work correctly when printing to the serial monitor. The first time you call `rf_driver.send()` in the loop, it works. The second time through the loop, and every time there after, it starts printing corrupted data. I don't have a definitive answer why this is happening, but I do have a way to "fix" it (or a "hack", if you prefer to call it that).

Using `memset()` to set the `msg_out` char array to all 0's **before** you use it seems to fix the problem. Here is a test sketch which is very similar to yours. I'm using some hard coded values for the sensor data because I don't have one of those sensors.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>
RH_ASK rf_driver;

float temp;
float hum;

char ch_temp[6];
char ch_hum[6];
char msg_out[12] = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  if (rf_driver.init()) {
    Serial.println("Radio transmitter initiated..");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Radio transmitter failed to initiate..");
    delay(1000);
  }
}
void loop() {

  // Set the buffer contents to all 0's
  memset(msg_out, 0, sizeof(msg_out));

  temp = 12.345;
  hum = 67.890;

  dtostrf(temp, 5, 2, ch_temp);
  dtostrf(hum, 5, 2, ch_hum);
  strcat(msg_out, ch_temp);
  strcat(msg_out, ",");
  strcat(msg_out, ch_hum);

  Serial.println(msg_out);
  rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg_out, strlen(msg_out));
  rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
  Serial.print("data sent, package size: ");
  Serial.println(strlen(msg_out));
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sketch is running on borrowed memory.
Every time the loop function runs, the new text is concatenated with `strcat()` and the buffer `msg_out` is never reset.
The first time 12 bytes are used, the second time 23 bytes, the third time 34, and so on.

The solution in the answer by @VE7JRO will fix that, but I prefer not to use `dtostrf()` and transmit binary data.

I see a few other problems as well:

- Why do you want to transmit readable ASCII text? Use binary data. 
  Either float numbers or integers. For example an integer in 1/100 degrees.
- The RadioHead library uses a lot of memory. You can not use an other 
  library that uses also a lot of memory.
- The value of '5' for dtostrf is the **minimal** width, 
  so you better make those arrays for example 20 bytes.
  I prefer to put those arrays temporarily on the stack.
- The DHT11 is not accurate. If you upgrade to a better sensor with I2C,
  then you need more libraries (the Wire library and a sensor library),
  and you might run out of sram memory.
- When using the RadioHead library in default mode, it uses three
  pins (rxPin=11, txPin=12, pttPin=10). You better add a comment
  section to your sketch to explain that you should not use those pins. 
  You have already a
  conflict at pin 10 for the DHT sensor and the pttPin.

---

The old and no longer supported VirtualWire library has some bugs, but it uses less memory than the RadioHead library. The RadioHead library is not optimized for Arduino boards like the Uno, Nano, Leonardo, and others. It even requires to `#include <SPI.h>` because that is often used with transceivers, even if the SPI bus is not used in RH_ASK mode (thanks to @VE7JRO for explaining this in the comment below).

---

**The easiest way** to transmit more than one value is with an array.

```
float myData[2];
myData[0] = 23.456;
myData[1] = 68.0;
rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)myData, sizeof(myData));
```

The `sizeof()` is not a real function, it tells the compiler to fill in the size of that variable. Since a `float` is 4 bytes, you may also fill in the number 8 for the second parameter.

There are a number of solutions for the receiver. I like to use a pointer to the buffer, but perhaps it is easier to copy them to variables with `memcpy()`.

```
float myData[2];
if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {
  if (buflen == sizeof(myData) {  // extra check
    memcpy((uint_8 *)myData, buf, sizeof(myData));
    Serial.println(myData[0]);
    Serial.println(myData[1]);
  }
}
```

When the receiver is also an Arduino board, then there should be no problem. When the receiver is something else, you might have to check if the [byte-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is the same. The `float` variable of a Arduino is 100% IEEE compatible, but sometimes it is easier to use only integers.

**The most common way** is to use a `struct`. A `struct` is a package that can hold all sorts of data (integers, bytes, arrays, and so on). The receiver and the sender should have exactly the same definition for the `struct` of course.

Comment: The OP may not be using SPI. If you remove the include from the sketch, it won't compile. There is a sketch called ask_transmitter.pde that comes with the library. It has a comment beside the SPI include that says: "Not actually used but needed to compile". I am new to Arduino, so I do not understand this comment. If none of the RadioHead files use any functions, etc. in the SPI library, why won't it compile with out it? I second your recommendation to get rid of the "low quality" sensor the OP is using. For $1.28USD, you can get a decent I2C Bosch sensor like a BMP280 at Aliexpress.com.

Comment: @VE7JRO right, I knew it but forgot about it.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! Really appriciate it!

Comment: @Jot Thank you for this thorough answer! Really appriciate it!! The reason i convert into Char* is to put it together, so i can send it in one package and then later on an other MCU easily take it apart and display seperatly. How would i go about putting to floats together and being able to seperate them later?

I've tried VirtualWire, but in this case this is alll this MCU is supposed to do. But I will keep this in mind in the future! Thanks! 

This project is for a school assignment, but i've noticed the DHT11 is not very reliable.. 
Thanks for pointing out the PIN conflict!!

Comment: @Love.Berg I have added an extra section to transmit an array. It is transmitted as binary data and received as binary data, so all you have to do is to take the binary data from the float variables, transmit them and in the receiver put the binary data back into float variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but here goes:

`msg_out[]` is a global but it doesn't need to be. Move it's definition and initialization into loop(), the only function that uses it. Then it gets initialized at every entry to loop() rather than just once at program initialization. There's no need to clear the array; just zeroing the zero-th element of it initializes it for character-string use, and that is what your initializer now does (but only once).